# Entity framework relationships - sql errors

Tags: .net, entity-framework, model-view-controller, ef-code-first

I have a project in which i'm trying to implement a (seemingly) simple shopping cart. Below are the relevant entities. I've gotten a variety of errors more often than not to do with an order_Id column name being invalid. So I suspect there is something wrong with the relationship between orders and items, but I also think there may be something much bigger that I'm missing in terms of approach. Any advice would be appreciated.

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public byte[] Thumbnail { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool OnSale { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}
public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<Item> Items { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
public class MyCart
{
    [Key]
    [ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
    public string MyCartId { get; set; }
    public IDictionary<Item, int> ItemsHash { get; set; }      
}

public class User
{
    public int Id{ get; set; }
    public int CreditCard { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int CCExpMonth { get; set; }
    public int CCExpYear { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Order> Orders { get; set; }
    public virtual MyCart Cart { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I Correct your entities like below :

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    [InverseProperty("Items")]
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int UserId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    [InverseProperty("Orders")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("Order")]
    public virtual ICollection<Item> Items { get; set; }        
}

public class MyCart
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("User")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CreditCard { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public int CCExpMonth { get; set; }
    public int CCExpYear { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [InverseProperty("User")]
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }

    public virtual MyCart Cart { get; set; }
}


protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<MyCart>()
        .HasKey(e => e.UserId);

    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
                .HasOptional(s => s.Cart) // Mark MyCart is optional for User
                .WithRequired(ad => ad.User); // Create inverse relationship

}
```

**Update :**

```
public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual int OrderId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OrderId")]
    **[InverseProperty("Items")]**
    public virtual Order Order { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by how a column of a single OrderId could be of use in the Item entity since an item is bound to belong to many orders. Similarly, how could there be an inverse property on orders when the order entity doesn't have a property named "Orders".
Besides my lack of understanding the update-database command failed because inverse property attribute on property 'Order' in the Item entity is not valid, and also the property 'Orders' is not a valid navigation property on the Order entity.

Comment: Still no joy. Package manager error reads: 
Either the parameter objname is ambiguous or the claimed objtype (COLUMN) is wrong.